# Master/details view with Backbone router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, master-detail

I saw a similar question here: [Backbone.js Master-Detail scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308719/backbone-js-master-detail-scenario) but I wanted a little more clarification on the "architecture" of a Master/Detail view using the Backbone.js philosophy.

I have a single Router in my app, that is responsible for instantiating one of two collection views. Say one is `Questions` and the other is `Committees`. There are two anchor links at the top that route to `#questions-view` and `#committees-view` respectively, which is picked up by the router and correctly switches views. I have all that working. Should I have a global `App` view keeps track of all these elements, like how some tutorials do it, or is having the `Router` at the top level good enough?

Furthermore, in my `committees` view, I would have a list of the committees, and when clicked, it would update another box on the page with the list of questions for that committee. This wouldn't be difficult, but I also want to have it trigger the router, and that view doesn't have access to the `Router`, and I'm not sure if it should. For example, I would like navigating to `..#committees/5` load up the view with the committee with id 5 selected, showing all those questions. I have posted some JS of the basics of the code I am using. I could easily have a details subview in my `MRFQuestionsCommitteeView.js` that updates on click events, but it is triggering the router that is confusing me.

Thanks for any help!

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      ''                : 'home',
      'question-view'   : 'home',
      'committee-view(/:committeeId)'  : 'committeeView'
    },


    home: function() {
        var $this = this;
        var prom = new MRFQuestions().fetch({
            success: function(coll) {
                $this.loadView(new MRFQuestionsView({ collection: coll, el: $('#ViewContainer') }) );
            }
        });
    },

    committeeView: function(committeeId) {
        var id = parseInt(committeeId, 10);
        var self = this;
        var c = new Committees();
        c.fetch({
            success: function(data) {
                var x = self.loadView(new MRFQuestionsCommitteesView({ collection: c, el: $('#Container2') }));               
                $.when(x).then(function() {
                    self.view.loadDetailPage(5);
                });
            }
        });
    },

    loadView: function(view) {
        this.view && this.view.remove();
        this.view = view;
        return this.view.render();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You router should be something like this

```
 var pageRootEl = $('.page-container');
 var currentPage ;
 var currentPageId = defaultPage;

 var defaultPage = 'page1';

 var paramsToObject = function(params) {
      if (!params) {
          return {};
      }
      var paramsArray = _.map(params.split(';'), function(str) {
          return str.split('=');
      });
      var obj = {};
      _.each(paramsArray, function(arr) {
          obj[arr[0]] = arr[1];
      });
      return obj;
  };


 var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
     routes: {
         ':pageId': 'renderPage',
         ':pageId/*params': 'renderPage',
         '':'renderDefaultPage',

     },
     renderPage: function (pageId, params) {
         var paramsObject = paramsToObject(params);

         if(currentPageId === pageId && currentPage){
             currentPage.model.set(paramsObject);
             return;
         }

         if(currentPage){
             currentPage.remove();
         }
         pageRootEl.empty();


         switch (pageId) {
             case 'page1':
                 $.getScript('pages/' + pageId + ".js", function () {
                     currentPage = new Page1.View({

                     });

                     currentPage.render().$el.appendTo(pageRootEl);
                 })
                 break;

             case 'page2':
                 $.getScript('pages/' + pageId + ".js", function () {
                     currentPage = new Page2.View({
                     });
                     currentPage.render().$el.appendTo(pageRootEl);
                 })
                 break;

             case 'page3':
                 $.getScript('pages/' + pageId + ".js", function () {
                     currentPage = new Page3.View({
                     });
                     currentPage.render().$el.appendTo(pageRootEl);
                 })
                 break;
         }


     },
     renderDefaultPage: function(){
         this.renderPage(defaultPage);
     }
 })


 var router = new Router();


 Backbone.history.start({
     root: this.root
 });
```

You can see that every router call will go through same function, if pageId changes, then currentPage is replaced with new page, otherwise new params just get added to page Model, in page view you can listen for changes, and handle selection, showing questions etc. Your url pattern should be like #pageId/param1=value1;param2=value2;param3=value3. This pattern lets you add more parameter and scale your application.

Comment: I don't know if this is really what I'm looking for, although it is a useful pattern. Are you saying have this generic handler, have them click a link that should route to the approriate number, and use those params in the route to call the appropriate function on my subview?

Comment: example looks complex, but could be customised to the requirement.